# How to prevent the gradient to pass through a calculation an a custom layer?

Tags: tensorflow, gradient, layer

I have a custom layer, which I want to train in a model.

The layer is defined by this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf

class RecLayer(layers.Layer):

  def __init__(self, units=32, input_dim=32):
    super(RecLayer, self).__init__()
    q_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
    self.q = tf.Variable(initial_value=q_init(shape=(units, input_dim),dtype='float32'),trainable=True)

    b_init = tf.zeros_initializer()
    self.b = tf.Variable(initial_value=b_init(shape=(units,),dtype='float32'),trainable=True)

    w_init = tf.zeros_initializer()
    self.w = tf.Variable(initial_value=w_init(shape=(units,units),dtype='float32'),trainable=True)
    self.units = units



  def call(self, inputs):

    self.x = inputs

    y = self.calc_y()
    activity = tf.tensordot(self.x,self.q, axes = [[1],[1]]) + tf.tensordot(y,self.w, axes = [[1],[0]]) + self.b
    output = tf.keras.activations.sigmoid(activity)
    return output


  def calc_y(self):
    y = tf.tensordot(self.x,self.q, axes = [[1],[1]])
    return y
```

My problem is that I want the gradient to ignore the gradient in respect to y.

So I am calculating

```
y = self.calc_y()
```

where the output depends on the trainable variable self.q.

But I want the gradient to treat y like a constant. Is that possible?